# Why an assertion on an empty list/dict fails?

Tags: python, elementtree

```py
assert {}
```

fails with `AssertionError`.

The issue led to this question was the following:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_element = ET.Element("tag")

assert xml_element
```

also fails with `AssertionError`.

`assert` evaluates the `expression`, I get that.

Also;

```py
if []:
    print("foo")
```

won't print anything because empty list returns `False` but,

```py
if [1]:
    print("foo")
```

would print foo.

My question is how could I have checked the internals of this behavior ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it fail? As you've seen with if, empty objects are false-y. And are you asking about lists and dicts, or why `Element("tag")` is false-y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When are things normally converted to true/false?

The question you are really asking is "what happens when you convert a list or dictionary to bool?". That's because `if x:` and `assert x` behave identically to if you wrote `if bool(x):` or `assert bool(x)`. (By the way, putting that explicit call to `bool()` in those places is bad form, precisely because it's redundant.)

The answer is that lists and dictionaries (and strings and other containers) are `True` when converted to `bool` if they are *not empty*. Conversely, they're `False` when converted to `bool` if they are *empty*.

The terminology often used for this is that non-empty containers are "truthy" and empty containers are "falsey".

This has the interesting consequence that `bool("False")` evaluates to `True` - because `"False"` is a non-empty string!

Aside from containers, there are some other usual cases: numbers are truethy if they're non-zero (i.e. `27` and `0.5` are truthey while `0` and `0.0` are falsey), and the value `None` is falsey.

### How to find out for other classes

> how could I have checked the internals of this behavior ?

As said above, anything that is sufficiently like a collection is truethy when it's non-empty; the usual test for whether it's "like a container" is whether you can call `len(x)` successfully on it, in which case it is truethy whenever `len(x)` is non-zero.

Even if a class is not a container (or a number), it is still possible that it has some meaningful conversion to `bool()`. In fact you can even define this on your own classes by defining a `__bool__()` method. The only way to determine that, short of looking at the source code, is to look at the documentation for the library you're using.

If there is no such conversion defined by the library then `bool(x)` will just always return `True` (that's the default for classes with no `__bool__()` or `__len__()` methods defined). See [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) in the official Python docs for a bit more information.

### ElementTree specifically

`xml.etree.ElementTree` in particular, things are unfortunately a bit confusing. A looks a little bit like a container of elements: `e[0]` returns the first child element, and `for child in e` returns all the children, and `len(e)` returns the count of child elements (these are all documented in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)). It therefore makes perfect sense that `bool(e)` is true exactly when there is at least one child element - that fits with how all the rest of Python works. However, as Tomerikoo's answer shows in the source code, while this currently works, it's deprecated and may not work in future. The docs also mention this but it is extremely buried:

> Caution: Elements with no subelements will test as `False`. This behavior will change in future versions. Use specific `len(elem)` or `elem is None` test instead.

The confusing logic behind this is explained in the code snippet below. The background is, `maybe_child = e.find("child")` finds a subelement of `e` with name `"child"`, or `None` if no such element is found. But `None` is falsey, so it's tempting to check if this search succeeded by writing `if maybe_child:` - but that will actually count as `False` if a child was found but had no child elements itself. Here's the snippet from the docs:

```
element = root.find('foo')

if not element:  # careful!
    print("element not found, or element has no subelements")

if element is None:
    print("element not found")
```

Answer (score 3):

From [`ElementTree`'s source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/35f041dd0171f575fc3adce1709b31fdf45a5ff6/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L214) (of class `Element`):

```
class Element:
[...]
    def __init__(self, tag, attrib={}, **extra):
        if not isinstance(attrib, dict):
            raise TypeError("attrib must be dict, not %s" % (
                attrib.__class__.__name__,))
        self.tag = tag
        self.attrib = {**attrib, **extra}
        self._children = []
[...]
    def __bool__(self):
        warnings.warn(
            "The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  "
            "Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.",
            FutureWarning, stacklevel=2
            )
        return len(self._children) != 0 # emulate old behaviour, for now
```

Since you just initialized a new element, its `_children` is an empty list (as can be seen in the `__init__`), so if you understand why `assert []` fails, you should understand why `assert xml_element` fails as-well.